# Efficient grouping in pandas based on another Series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I need to erform a grouped operation which is based on another boolean column in my `DataFrame`. It is most easily seen in an example: I have the following `DataFrame`:

```
    b          id   
0   False      0
1   True       0
2   False      0
3   False      1
4   True       1
5   True       2
6   True       2
7   False      3
8   True       4
9   True       4
10  False      4
```

and would like to obtain a column, whose elements are True if the `b` column is True and it is the last time it is True for a given `id`:

```
    b          id    lastMention
0   False      0     False
1   True       0     True
2   False      0     False
3   False      1     False
4   True       1     False
5   True       2     True
6   True       3     True
7   False      3     False
8   True       4     False
9   True       4     True
10  False      4     False
```

I have a code that achieves this, although inefficiently:

```
def lastMentionFun(df):
    b = df['b']
    a = b.sum()
    if a > 0:
        maxInd = b[b].index.max()
        df.loc[maxInd, 'lastMention'] = True
    return df

df['lastMention'] = False
df = df.groupby('id').apply(lastMentionFun)
```

Can someone propose what is the correct pythonic approach to do this nice and fast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first filter values where True in column `b` and then get `max` index value with `groupby` and aggregating `max`:

```
print (df[df.b].reset_index().groupby('id')['index'].max())
id
0    1
1    4
2    6
4    9
Name: index, dtype: int64
```

Then replace values `False` by index values with `loc`:

```
df['lastMention'] = False
df.loc[df[df.b].reset_index().groupby('id')['index'].max(), 'lastMention'] = True

print (df)
        b  id  lastMention
0   False   0        False
1    True   0         True
2   False   0        False
3   False   1        False
4    True   1         True
5    True   2        False
6    True   2         True
7   False   3        False
8    True   4        False
9    True   4         True
10  False   4        False
```

Another solution - get `max` index values with `groupby` and `apply`, then test membership of values in index with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) - output is `boolean Series`:

```
print (df[df.b].groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.index.max()))
id
0    1
1    4
2    6
4    9
dtype: int64

df['lastMention'] = df.index.isin(df[df.b].groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.index.max()))
print (df)
        b  id lastMention
0   False   0       False
1    True   0        True
2   False   0       False
3   False   1       False
4    True   1        True
5    True   2       False
6    True   2        True
7   False   3       False
8    True   4       False
9    True   4        True
10  False   4       False
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the most efficient method, but it uses only built-in functions (the main one being "cumsum" and then max to check that it equals the last one - pd.merge is just used to put the max back in the table, maybe there's a better way for doing that?).

```
df['cum_b']=df.groupby('id', as_index=False).cumsum()
df = pd.merge(df, df[['id','cum_b']].groupby('id', as_index=False).max(), how='left', on='id', suffixes=('','_max'))
df['lastMention'] = np.logical_and(df.b, df.cum_b == df.cum_b_max)
```

P.S. The dataframe you specified in the example changes slightly from the first to the second snippet, I hope I've interpreted your request correctly!